# Where can I get Debian iso file (with just a terminal)?

Tags: debian, system-installation, iso

I went through the Debian website www.debian.org, but I couldn't find any iso to run the system with terminal (operating system should have a Debian core).
The iso file should be completely standalone.

Comment: See also lubuntu (debian package based)

Comment: I had a look, the smallest official ISO (apart from netinstall) for Debian 9 is the XFCE CD at 650M. The live images are all DVD size.  I believe there used to be smaller images of ["Debian Standard"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87182/whats-the-difference-between-debian-standard-and-gnome) (no graphical interface), but they appear to have stopped. Beyond that, this question is too broad for us to answer here, sorry. It doesn't define what you would consider to be an acceptable broadening of your terms.

Comment: It looks like if 650M is too big, you're _really_ out of luck for an ISO nowadays. Find alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

You’ll find the network installation images (the smallest images) [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst).

If the device you’re installing on needs firmware, you’ll find it easier to use one of the unofficial images [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/9.3.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-cd/) (these are still built on Debian’s infrastructure, they’re unofficial because they don’t satisfy [Debian’s Free Software Guidelines](https://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines)).

Comment: I am  looking for just basic Debian iso without extra package's

Comment: The smallest standalone image you can get is the [XFCE CD](https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/). The network installation image is the smallest directly-usable image, but it requires an Internet connection. There’s no such thing as “extra packages” in Debian, packages are either part of Debian or they aren’t...

Comment: I just need basic files to run a desktop ( because of bandwidth issues in my area )

Comment: Get the network installation image then, that will ensure you use as little bandwidth as possible (assuming you’re not going to install it several times).

Comment: Any alternative ( standalone would be great )

Comment: The smallest standalone image is the XFCE CD.